# Given a sorted row of n numbers in SQL server, how do i find at what point the sum of the rows reach the value k?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, algorithm, math

Assume i got the below row of number and max quantity value is 10.

```
Quantity  BatchValue
2         0
4         0
4         0
6         1
8         2
```

Summation of 2+4+4 gives me a value less than or equal to max quatity 10 and so the batch value for those rows become 0. The pending rows are 6 and 8. They cannot be summed up to be < max quantity. So they will be seperate. Can we get an sql query or an algorith that can do this?

Comment: So what doesyour desired output look like? And what query have you tried?

Comment: Search this site for running total. It has been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice running sum routine you can use

```
create table #temp (rowid int identity,  quantity int)
insert #temp 
select quantity from yourtable order by your order

declare @holding table (quantity int, runningsum int)
declare @quantity int 
declare @running int=0
declare @iterator int = 1 
while @iterator<=(select max(rowid) from #temp)
begin 
select @quantity=quantity from #temp where rowid=@iterator
set @running=@quantity+@running
insert @holding 
select @quantity, @running
set @iterator=@iterator+1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited code from Daniel Marcus above to give the actual response requested in query.

```
    CREATE TABLE #temp(rowid int identity(1,1), quantity int)

    INSERT INTO #temp
    SELECT 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 6
    UNION ALL SELECT 8

    declare @batchValue int = 0 ,@maxquantity int = 10
    declare @holding table (quantity int, batchvalue int)
    declare @quantity int 
    declare @running int=0
    declare @iterator int = 1 

    while @iterator<=(select max(rowid) from #temp)
    begin 
    select @quantity=quantity from #temp where rowid=@iterator
    set @running=@quantity+@running

    -- Newly added condition
    if (@running > @maxquantity)    BEGIN

        SET @batchValue = @batchValue + 1 -- increment the batch value
        insert @holding select @quantity, @batchValue
        SET @running = @quantity -- reset the running value

        END
    ELSE
        insert @holding select @quantity, @batchValue

    set @iterator=@iterator+1
    end
    SELECT * FROM @holding
    DROP TABLE #temp
```

Hope the snippet works for your purpose. I tested this in SQL azure and provides the result you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

--The below query will help you if you working on sql server 2012 or higher
CREATE TABLE #RUN_TOT(ID INT)

INSERT INTO #RUN_TOT VALUES(2),(4),(4),(6),(8)

;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) RNUM,
CASE 
WHEN SUM(ID) OVER(ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) <=
(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #RUN_TOT) THEN 0
ELSE
ID
END VAL
FROM #RUN_TOT
)

SELECT ID,VAL FROM CTE WHERE VAL=0
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY VAL) VAL FROM CTE WHERE VAL<>0